# ¿Como puedo conectar mi codigo a una base de datos en phpmyadmin?

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, vscode, xampp

Queria ver como es posible conectar mi vscode a una base de datos utilizando xampp phpmyadmin y tambien como insertar el valor introducido de algo como `System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del cliente: ");` a una tabla/columna en especifico.

Comment: phpMyAdmin, como su nombre indica, funciona con PHP no con Java, por lo tanto, no acabo de entender que pretendes hacer... 
Para Java existen librerías para conectarte a BD y realizar operaciones en ellas... phpMyAdmin es simplemente un cliente de BD que te permite realizar las operaciones vía WEB. Lo que entiendo es que tú tienes que realizar una app o script o algo que realice operaciones en la BD. Para esto no te hace falta phpMyAdmin para nada.

Answer (score 0):

Debes conectar tu codigo a la base de datos a traves de el driver especifico de tu base de datos. Despues creas la conexión, realizas las consultas y finalmente cierras la conexión.
PhpMyAdmin es un entorno gráfico para administrar tu base de datos via web.

Este es un ejemplo para la conexión a MariaDB

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConexionMariaDB {
private static final String DRIVER = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"; //es el driver que descargas de su web y añadir la librería o a traves de Maven
private static final String URL_CONEXION = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/Pruebas"; //cambias localhost/pruebas por tu dirección y nombre de base de datos
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
    final String usuario = "user_db"; //tu user admin
    final String password = "password_db"; //tu pass
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL_CONEXION, usuario, password);
        String selectTableSQL = "SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDOS FROM Usuarios"; //la consulta que quieras ,si es un insert  u otra update debes usar statement.executeUpdate(aquiLaUpdate)
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String nombre= rs.getString("NOMBRE");
            String apellidos=rs.getString("APELLIDOS");
            System.out.println(nombre+" | "+apellidos);
     
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
  } 
}
```